# Join a room in socket.io on postman

Tags: node.js, socket.io, postman, socket.io-client

how do i resolve this socket.to(user).emit("add-message", AddMessage); on postman using socket.io

i tried declaring the user id as the event listener and "add-message" as the event description but it's still not working

Comment: What hast postman todo with this? Neiter does postman support the socket.io protocol nor does it load the socket.io client. Please clarify your issue/problem!

Comment: I have been able to resolve it. All I had to do was add each client on postman to a room that the server recognices and that did the trick for me